# Infinite intersection of open subsets are open

Tags: general-topology

What is know about topological space in which infinite  intersection of open subsets are open?

For example, every open subsets are also closed and the inverse holds?

Other properties are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might search for "clopen".

Comment: I know that concept. Can the titled  topology characterized by clopen subsets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such spaces are called [Alexandroff spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology). You can find a short overview paper on then [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.2136.pdf).

They're not studied very much, it's a niche thing.

Answer (score 1):

About your second question:
Spaces, where each open set is closed, are called *partition spaces*, since this is equivalent to have a base, which is a partition of the set.
It is easy to see that a space is a parttion space, iff it is Alexandroff and regular.
In particular, there are even finite topological spaces (hence Alexandroff), which are not partition spaces, e.g. the Sierpinski space (= two element space with exactly one isolated point).